# When is heightForRowAt called for UITableView? / When is a UITableView "displayed"?

Tags: ios, uitableview

According to the UIKit API reference...

> Every time a table view is displayed, it calls `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` on the delegate for each of its rows...

Is this accurate/unambiguous?

If so, can anyone list or perhaps link to a list of all situations that count as a table view "being displayed" and thus triggering `heightForRowAt`?

- Does `beginUpdates()`/`endUpdates()` trigger the display of a table view?
- Does `reloadData()` trigger it?
- Does anything else?

Comment: 1. `endUpdates()` will trigger the tableView cells. 2. Yes `reloadData()` also redraws the whole tableView cells. 3. Resetting the `datasource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heightForRowAt` will be called anytime the table needs to know the height of a cell and the height of the table view.

This happens:

- The first time the table view is loaded.
- Anytime a row is added or updated (`insertRows/Sections`, `reloadRows/Sections`)
- When the table is reloaded (`reloadData()`)
- When `endUpdates()` is called.
- Anytime the table needs to be redrawn for any reason.

Comment: Thanks! And a followup question, if you don't mind, to avoid creating a separate question: this means that whenever heightForRowAt is called, the tableView.contentSize.height property will be updated based on the value returned by heightForRowAt, right?

Comment: Yes, it should. Besides needing to know a given row's height to show the row properly, the table view needs to know its entire height so the scroll view's `contentSize` can be set properly.